# How to make a continuous listener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning so perhaps my question could be rephrased or re-worded.

1. When I click div=> variable= variable+1;
2. What I want is when 'variable===3', it console.log('I am 3).

My script is not doing what I am trying to do, but this is my try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    element = document.getElementById("id");
    variable=0;

    function loading(){

        element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        variable=variable+1;
        console.log(variable);
        });

    };


    function check(){
    if(variable===3){console.log('I am 3');};

    };

    loading();
    check();


    </script>
```

Should I call check() each time object is clicked? Or should I create a listener to call check() every time 'variable' is changing? Or another solutions?

Comment: The `if (variable === 3) { c.l('3'); }` should be moved inside the click handler. or call `check` from handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `check` from the event handler:

```
function loading(){
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        variable=variable+1;
        check();
        console.log(variable);
    });
}
```

Calling `check` whenver `variable` changes is your only option with a variable.

If you want to do the check any time the value of something changes, you could use an object property instead, with a setter:

```
var obj = (function() {
    var value = 0;

    return {
        get value() {
            return value;
        },
        set value(newValue) {
            value = newValue;
            if (value == 3) {
                console.log("I am 3");
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Then:

```
function loading(){
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        obj.value = obj.value + 1; // Or ++obj.value;
        console.log(obj.value);
    });
}
```

Whenever you change the value of `obj.value`, the setter function is called, and so you can do your check there.

Note that this is a feature added in ES5 (2009), so it's not present in older JavaScript engines such as the one in IE8.

---

Some other notes:

1. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Declare your variables.
2. `;` don't go at the end of function *declarations*, or *blocks*. Just statements that don't end with a block.
3. Consistent indentation aids readability.
4. `variable = variable + 1;` is fine, but you also have the option of being more concise: `++variable;`

So:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
var variable = 0;

function loading(){
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        ++variable;
        console.log(variable);
        check();
    });
}

function check(){
    if (variable===3) {
        console.log('I am 3');
    }
}

loading();
check();
```

Comment: So the only way to make check() checking variable all the time is calling it on event? Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Sulot: Correct. But if you want something that will always do the check any time its value is changed, you can do a *property* -- I'll add an example.

Comment: @Sulot: Added a note about using a property with a setter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last question: how do you name (I'll google it) the way you call your function with the '(' before and (); at the end? `(function(){})();`

Comment: @Sulot: That whole thing is called an *inline-invoked function expression* ("IIFE").

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - it's just that your check doesn't need to be a separate function.

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
var variable = 0;

function increment(variable) {
    variable++;
    console.log(variable);

    if (variable === 3) {
        console.log('I am 3');
    }
}


element.addEventListener("click", function(){increment(variable);}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but imagine a lot of things are happening and a lot a 'click' in different 'div' can be made to change 'variable'. How can I do an ongoing check of variable? (I didn't downvote you that's the other guy. I upvoted you for your VERY quick answer)

Comment: You don't need to do an ongoing check of the variable - you only ever need to check the variable when `increment();` runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("id");
var variable = 0;

element.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  variable += 1;
  
  check();

});


function check(){
  
  // for demo purposes, let's change the button text
  element.innerHTML = variable === 3 ? 'I am 3' : 'click';
  
  if(variable === 3)
    console.log('I am 3');

};

check();
```

```html
<button id="id">click</button>
```

Pointers:

Use `var` to declare new variables in the current scope.